# Is it safe to connect 220v and 110v neutral lines together on the same breaker bar?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Saw my electrician split the breaker box into 2 sections. He used one side for 220V with the main switch (ON/OFF) connected to 220 supply (hot), and also connected to the Neutral breaker bar.

He connected a breaker on the 220 side to a step down transformer, and brought the 110v line
back into the box and connected that to another breaker which he used as a 110 (On/Off) switch.
Then connected that to another breaker for appliances etc.

Noticed that he connected all the Neutrals from the 220v breakers to the Breaker box Neutral bar, and also connected all the neutrals from the 110v breakers to the same Breaker box Neutral bar. Is that safe?

Comment: Sounds very strange. But there may be other details we're missing. Can you upload a picture of the breaker panel?

Comment: Add your location also, it sounds like North America, but we usually don't need a step down transformer for 110v.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Can you provide us with the make and model of the breaker box and the step-down transformer?

Comment: "Neutral breaker"?  Methinks there is a nomenclature issue here or some kind of confusion.  Are you from a 240V country or the Philippines and seeing a North American panel for the first time?